# В laravel 5 читать данные из postgresql-функции

Tags: postgresql, laravel

Всем привет,
В laravel 5.5 я получаю данные из postgresql-функции

```
DB::select($sql)
```

где sql :

```
select  pd_report_orders_sum_by_categories( p_category_list := ARRAY[102,17]::integer[], p_last_operation_date_from := '2012-09-20', p_last_operation_date_till := '2017-09-29', p_status := 'O', p_sort_categories := 'sum', p_limit := null )


и функция определена как:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pd_report_orders_sum_by_categories(p_category_list integer[], p_last_operation_date_from timestamp without time zone, p_last_operation_date_till timestamp without time zone, p_status type_order_status, p_sort_categories character varying DEFAULT 'by_sum_asc'::character varying, p_limit integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(category_name character varying, category_slug character varying, category_id smallint, sold_sum numeric, qty_sum bigint)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

SELECT c.name as category_name,

   c.slug as category_slug,

   pc.category_id,

   sum( oi.qty*oi.price ) AS sold_sum,

   sum( oi.qty ) AS qty_sum

  from pd_order_item as oi join

      pd_product_category as pc on pc.product_id = oi.product_id join

      pd_order as o on o.id = oi.order_id join

      pd_category as c on c.id = pc.category_id

  WHERE ( CASE when p_category_list IS NOT NULL THEN pc.category_id = ANY (p_category_list) else true END ) AND 

       ( o.last_operation_date BETWEEN coalesce(p_last_operation_date_from,pd_f_min_timestamp()) AND coalesce(p_last_operation_date_till,pd_f_max_timestamp()) ) AND

       ( CASE when p_status IS NOT NULL THEN o.status = p_status else true END )

  group by pc.category_id, category_name, category_slug

  ORDER BY

        CASE WHEN p_sort_categories = 'by_sum_asc' THEN

            sum( oi.qty*oi.price )

        end ASC,

        CASE WHEN p_sort_categories = 'by_sum_desc' THEN

            sum( oi.qty*oi.price )

        end DESC,

        CASE WHEN p_sort_categories = 'by_sum_category_name' THEN

            c.name

        end ASC

  LIMIT p_limit ;

$function$
```

И я получаю на выходе массив :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pd_report_orders_sum_by_categories] => (Music,music,4,2.43,1)
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pd_report_orders_sum_by_categories] => ("Computer Accessories",computer-accessories,1,25.75,1)
        )
```

я парсер написал - но он работает правильно, если в текстовой строке нет запятой - иначе данные неправильны.
А как правильно ?

Спасибо!